# Stack corruption using sscanf

Tags: c++, scanf, stack-corruption

I have the following code to convert 2 hex digits to a byte value:

```
const char* data= "Some hex string";
unsigned char temp=' ';
sscanf(data, "%2hhx", &temp);
```

When running it I get a run time exception, saying

> stack around variable temp is corrupted

What am I doing wrong? AFAIK `2hhx` should convert two bytes to one...

Comment: Are you sure that the `hh` modifier is supported by your implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure your compiler and standard library support that particular specifier? It is new in C99.

Microsoft for example doesn't support it, according to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx

This means that the `hh` is probably interpreted as a single `h` and it therefore expects a pointer to `unsigned short`, not `unsigned char`.

Comment: Is so, what can I use instead?

Comment: Just read into a bigger integer. The `2` in the specification still ensures that it won't read more than you want.