# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED when calling free() after sscanf()

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to write a function to convert a string of hex values to a byte array. What's wrong with this code?

After calling free() I get the error HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED. If I comment the call to sscanf everything is normal. Does sscanf writes something beyond the memory allocated by malloc ?

```
unsigned char* hextobytes(const string& hex) {
    size_t size = hex.size() / 2;
    unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    const string::value_type* pos = hex.c_str();

    for (size_t c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        sscanf((pos + 2 * c), "%2hhx", bytes + c);
    }

    return bytes;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    string hex = "FFFF";
    unsigned char* bytes = hextobytes(hex);
    free(bytes);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I'm working on Visual Sudio 2013

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new` (and try avoid using it explicitly: read about smart pointers and containers)

Comment: Hm.... this is so very much C I have to look hard to see the C++ part of it...

Comment: @DevSolar Look closer, it is right there, in the 3rd expression of the for loop :)

Comment: @Lundin: And he's casting the return value of `malloc()`, *that* is a dead giveaway. :)  {I am a baaaaad person...}

Comment: Is the code you show the actual code causing the problem? Because I can't see anything wrong with it, and I also ran it through a memory debugger and it didn't complain at all. The only problem is that it won't handle input strings with uneven number of digits.

Comment: There is no bug in this code.  Keep in mind that heap corruption is usually reported long after the damage was done and often was not caused by the code that made the allocation.

Comment: @Joachim yes it is the actual code and nothing else is declared or executed before or after.

Comment: @Basil same problem with new

Comment: Remember that `HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED` can identify a heap corruption that happened earlier in the execution of your program. It may be some other bug of your program or even caused by using a dll created with a different compiler (result of having 2 incompatible heaps).

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988901/stack-corruption-using-sscanf).

The Microsoft version of scanf does not support the length modifier 'hh' to specify a unsigned char. It supports the modifier 'h' which specify a short int.

Using an array of short int instead of unsigned char resolves my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it is stated policy of Microsoft to not really bother with continued updating of their compiler's C capabilities. One more reason to ditch the C style and go for proper C++ idioms.

Comment: @DevSolar although it doesn't resolve the actual problem I will keep your solution for the C++ style example, thanks

Comment: Well, depending on how you define "the actual problem". ;-) I consider C style coding in a C++ environment, especially naked pointers and the use of arrays, to *be* a problem; simply because so many issues simply won't surface in proper C++. (Which, of course, has its *own* collection of issues, but you see where I am coming from.) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem with your source is that it is C++, but the programming is so very C style.

Others have pointed out that the code as posted does not exhibit the error you claimed.

But allow me, if I may, to show how this could be done C++ style, *with no chance of heap corruption whatsoever* because C++ gives us all the tools we need to avoid "naked" pointers:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector< unsigned char > hextobytes( const std::string & hex )
{
    std::vector< unsigned char > rc;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < hex.size(); i += 2 )
    {
        // this may throw std::invalid_argument if no
        // conversion can be performed
        // formally std::out_of_range would be also a
        // possibility, but not with a two-digit hex...
        rc.push_back( static_cast< unsigned char >(
            std::stoul( hex.substr( i, 2 ), 0, 16 ) )
        );
    }
    return rc;
}

int main()
{
    std::string hex( "FFFF" );
    std::vector< unsigned char > bytes = hextobytes( hex );
    for ( auto a : bytes )
    {
        std::cout << static_cast< int >( a ) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```